# Oracle (SQL): How to get SQL query syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

A table (ex: `A`) has three columns `id, name, amount`. `Amount` has some +ve,-ve and zero values. How to write a query to get the amount in such a way that it gives as a result first +ve then -ve then zeros? PFA for the sample table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results

Comment: amount is varchar/number or other type?

Comment: @user7294900, number type but has mixed values some +ve, _ve and zeros as explained above.

Comment: @ManojKnitan why zero are after negative numbers? (and after positive)

Comment: @GordonLinoff PFA for the sample table with data.

Comment: @user7294900 that is the actual need in the way to get the solution of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 3 groups one after the other:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY 
    (CASE 
        WHEN amount > 0 then 1
        WHEN amount < 0 then 2
        ELSE 3
    END),
    Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for `order by` with a `case` expression?

```
select a.*
from a
order by (case when a.amount > 0 then 1
               when a.amount < 0 then 2
               else 3
          end),
         a.amount desc;
```

Comment: If I remove a.* with * then it's working fine otherwise showing syntax error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ManojKnitan . . .`a.*` should be fine if `a` is the name of the table.